# getting an warning cast to pointer from integer of different size

Tags: c++, c

I am currently working on porting from 32 bit to 64 bit. And I am getting a warning:

> cast to pointer from integer of different size

In the following code

```
AcLogFileWrite(
    (FILE *) pOut->pTrace->logFileHandle, /* warning in this line */
    outRecord,
    outRecordLen);
```

and prototype of `AcLogFileWrite()` is

```
int AcLogFileWrite(
    FILE * handle,
    char * data,
    int    bytes);
```

Here the parameter `pOut->pTrace->logFileHandle` is of type `int`.

How can I fix this warning?

Comment: Check if both 'int' and 'FILE*' have the same size. It might be that the pointer has twice the size of its 32 bit version

Comment: `AcLogFileWrite()` expecting first argument as `FILE` pointer but you are passing `int` type.

Comment: Why is it an `int` in the first place? correct this to be `FILE *` or if you absolutely must, `void *`.

Comment: @venki the int is been typecast to FILE*  

(FILE*)pOut->pTrace->logFileHandle

Comment: How does `logFileHandle` get initialised?

Comment: @alk logFileHandle is in a struct and there it is int
typedef struct {
int                 logFileHandle;
}traceControlSt;

Comment: I wasn't asking how `logFileHandle` is defined, but I was trying to ask how it gets initialised, gets its initial value assigned, before being passed to `AcLogFileWrite()`.

Comment: @alk it will have the value from other same named variable in other struct which is  also int.

Comment: And if you trace this back, where does the value come from?

Comment: it will have value from atoi() function

Comment: Is there some reason `logFileHandle` has to be of type `int`? If not, change it to `FILE *`. If so, you'll have to create some mapping of integers to `FILE*`'s.

Comment: "*from `atoi()`*" sounds weird. Do you have by any means a chance to give an example of the typically value you receive for it?

Comment: Either create `pOut->pTrace->logFileHandle,` as `FILE *` or change and use lower level file descriptors and read/write for IO.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes there is reason for logFileHandle to be of type int because this variable is being used by many other functions as a int data type

Comment: Then you'll need to construct a mapping between integers and `FILE*`s. Every time you allocate a file, add it to the table and assign it an integer. (Or change those other functions to take something like an `intptr_t`.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz ok now I got it. Really Thanks

Comment: @newbie as `AcLogFileWrite()` function is expecting address you need to pass only address not value have you tried `AcLogFileWrite(
   (FILE *) &pOut->pTrace->logFileHandle, /* warning in this line */
    outRecord,
    outRecordLen);` this?

Answer (score 0):

You can’t store 64 bits in a 32-bit int.  If `logFileHandle` has to store a pointer, the only integer types that can safely do that are `uintptr_t` or `intptr_t` from `<stdint.h>`.  Or you can `typedef void*`.  Since you’re porting to a new ABI anyway, binary compatibility is not an issue and this is a good time to fix it.

If you absolutely cannot change the definition of the type from `int`, then you must compile under the `ILP64` model, in which `int`, `long` and `void*` are all 64 bits wide.

Comment: well logFileHandle is in a struct name pTrace and the data type of logFileHandle  there is int

Comment: in this code the logFileHandle which is int will be typecast to FILE* first and then will passed to FILE*

Comment: But, since a 32-bit `int` cannot hold a 64-bit `FILE*`, the resulting pointer will be garbage, and any attempt to dereference it will cause a segfault.  That”s why the compiler stops you from shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: @newbie - The cast only silences the compiler's warning. We are worried by the fact that a pointer in general doesn't fit in an `int`. For example, if you have a 64-bit pointer like `00007FF625921C8F`, the 32-bit `int` will just store `25921C8F`. And when you cast it back to a pointer, you get `0000000025921C8F`.

Comment: So either `typedef uintptr_t filehandle_t` or `typedef void* filehandle_t` and change the type to `filehandle_t`.  Or whatever matches your naming convention.

Comment: @Lorehead BoPersson   thanks now I got it..  really thankful for the help .

Answer (score 0):

If `logFileHandle` in fact is a file descriptor getting initialised using e.g. `open()` you want to use [`fdopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) on it and pass the function's result to `AcLogFileWrite()`.